# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CFCredentials_Exception' with message 'No credentials were provided for Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is killing me.I have done everything but not right as its not still giving me this error
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CFCredentials_Exception' with message 'No credentials were provided`. I am trying to upload files to S3 using AWS sdk 1.6 example and jquery file upload plugin.I found an example on the [wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki).
  
This is my file where I set the credentials `awssdk.php` from the wiki example

```
  require_once 'sdk.class.php';
  require_once 'utilities.class.php';
  require_once 'credential.class.php';
  if (!class_exists('CFCredentials'))require_once('credentials.class.php');
  $name=null;
  CFCredentials::set(array(
    $name => array(
            'key' => 'access key',
            'secret' => 'secret key',
            'certificate_authority' => false
    ),
    '@default' => $name
    ));
  if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');
   $s3 = new AmazonS3();
```

I am quite sure I should't need so many files but as the errors suggested I had to add the dependency classes.But still I get the above error. I also tried to include the `config.class.php`  file for credentials and still got this error.
I have been spending a lot of time on this and now kind of frustrated with this AWS sdk.
I am a bit new to OO PHP and probably hence finding it difficult.Experts please suggest  some solution to where I am wrong.

**EDIT:** I believe this class causes the issue,not sure how!!

```
   class CFCredentials
  {
/**
 * The key used to specify the default credential set
 */
const DEFAULT_KEY = 'my key';

/**
 * The key used to identify inherited credentials
 */
const INHERIT_KEY = 'my secret key';

/**
 * Stores the credentials
 */
protected static $credentials = array();

/**
 * Prevents this class from being constructed
 */
final private function __construct() {}

/**
 * Stores the credentials for re-use.
 *
 * @param array $credential_sets (Required) The named credential sets that should be made available to the application.
 * @return void
 */
// private $credential_sets = array('key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','certificate_authority' => false);

 public static function set(array $credential_sets)
 {
    // Make sure a default credential set is specified or can be inferred
    if (count($credential_sets) === 1)
    {echo "in count if-->".self::DEFAULT_KEY;
        $credential_sets[self::DEFAULT_KEY] = reset($credential_sets);
    }

    // Resolve any @inherit tags
    foreach ($credential_sets as $credential_name => &$credential_set)
    {
        if (is_array($credential_set))
        {
            foreach ($credential_set as $credential_key => &$credential_value)
            {
                if ($credential_key === self::INHERIT_KEY)
                {
                    if (!isset($credential_sets[$credential_value]))
                    {
                        throw new CFCredentials_Exception('The credential set, "' . $credential_value . '", does not exist and cannot be inherited.');
                    }

                    $credential_set = array_merge($credential_sets[$credential_value], $credential_set);
                    unset($credential_set[self::INHERIT_KEY]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Normalize the value of the @default credential set
    if (isset($credential_sets[self::DEFAULT_KEY]))
    {
        $default = $credential_sets[self::DEFAULT_KEY];
        if (is_string($default))
        {
            if (!isset($credential_sets[$default]))
            {
                throw new CFCredentials_Exception('The credential set, "' . $default . '", does not exist and cannot be used as the default credential set.');
            }

            $credential_sets[self::DEFAULT_KEY] = $credential_sets[$default];
        }
    }

    // Store the credentials
    self::$credentials = $credential_sets;
}

/**
 * Retrieves the requested credentials from the internal credential store.
 *
 * @param string $credential_set (Optional) The name of the credential set to retrieve. The default value is set in DEFAULT_KEY.
 * @return stdClass A stdClass object where the properties represent the keys that were provided.
 */

public static function get($credential_name = self::DEFAULT_KEY)
{
    //echo $credential_name; exit;
    // Make sure the credential set exists
    if (!isset(self::$credentials[$credential_name]))
    {
        throw new CFCredentials_Exception('The credential set, "' . $credential_name . '", does not exist and cannot be retrieved.');
    }

    // Return the credential set as an object
    return new CFCredential(self::$credentials[$credential_name]);
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of all available credential set names.
 *
 * @return CFArray A list of all available credential set names.
 */
public static function list_sets()
{
    return new CFArray(array_keys(self::$credentials));
}
}

class CFCredentials_Exception extends Exception {}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like whatever tutorial you are following is making this unnecessarily difficult. Try this:

```
require_once 'sdk.class.php';

$s3 = new AmazonS3(array(
    'key'    => 'your_aws_access_key_id',
    'secret' => 'your_aws_secret_key',
));
```

You shouldn't need to require any other files.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs.Actually I am using the old SDK as I I found a tutorial.Actually the issue was that I had to put right values here and it fixed the issue `/**
 * The key used to specify the default credential set
 */
const DEFAULT_KEY = 'my key';

/**
 * The key used to identify inherited credentials
 */
const INHERIT_KEY = 'my secret key';
` Now I want to integrate the plugin with the new SDK.I would like if you can help me with my further questions related to new SDK!! :)

Comment: Sure. The easiest way to get my attention is to post on the AWS PHP forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=80

Comment: I have posted my question on the forum here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=465795#465795

Answer (score 0):

```
You have set all Credential well but still you have leave one credential 'default_cache_config' => '' 
Just Put it in Credential array with some location for caching the default credential.
just have a look


$name=null;
     CFCredentials::set(array(
        $name => array(  

                'key' => 'access key',
                'secret' => 'secret key',
                 'default_cache_config' => '/home/user/any location',
                'certificate_authority' => false
        ),
        '@default' => $name
        ));**
```